# Why is my getActivity() null in this situation?

Tags: java, android, fragment

I do not understand why my getActivity() that is around my runonUiThread is coming back null. Below is the code for where I am having the problem. I think it has something to do with where I place my onAttach method but I am not sure. Also please ingore all the comments as I will clean my code when this bug is fixed. Also note this is the java code for a fragment. Thank you.

```
 public void onAttach(Context context){
           super.onAttach(context);
           Activity a;
          if(context instanceof Activity)
          {
              a=(Activity) context;
          }

     }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment



        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //setCont(R.layout.fragment_level_one);
       // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_one,container, false);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_one, container, false);

        //creating viewables and such
        viewer = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.view_level);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        failButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.failureButton);
        countDownMain = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countDownMain);
        countDownBeginText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countDownBeginText);
        beginButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.beginButton);

        /*if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeView(view);
            }
        }
        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_one, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {

        }*/

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
        img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        img.setOnTouchListener(new LevelOneFragment.ChoiceTouchListener());

        //begin random movement
        if(isAdded()) {
            startRandomButton(img);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("line 98 is", " is null");
        }

        //setting up button for failure CORRECT TO TAKE YOU TO THE MAIN MENU
        failButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainMenu.class));
            }
        });

        //setting countdown text to 3
        countDownBeginText.setText(":3");

        //begin countdown from three
        beginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View beginT) {
                CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(3*1000, 3) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        countDownBeginText.setText(":" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
                        //add possible sound here every tick
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        beginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        countDownBeginText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        //countdown from 60------- change parameters in count down timer to the time desired
                        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60*1000, 3) {
                            @Override
                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinishedMain) {

                                countDownMain.setText(":" + millisUntilFinishedMain/1000);
                                //add possible sound here every tick
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You lose", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                //rest of text in method is trial

                                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainMenu.class ));

                            }
                        }.start();

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
        return view; //inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_one,container, false);
    }
    //getting screen size
    public static Point getDisplaySize(@NonNull Context context){

        Point point = new Point();
        WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        manager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
        return point;
    }

    //randomly move
    public void randomMovement(ImageView img){
        //int   x = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(getActivity()).x);
        //int   y = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(getActivity()).y);

        if(isAdded()) {
            int   x = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(getActivity()).x);
            int   y = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(getActivity()).y);
            img.setY(y);
            img.setX(x);
        }
        else
            Log.d("Random mover is null", " is null");

    }

    //creating timer
    public void startRandomButton(final ImageView img){
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(isAdded()){
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { //best method in the entire world-- use when trying to update ui in the background
                   @Override
                    public void run() {
                        randomMovement(img);
                    }
                });}else{
                    Log.d("Fragment one", "Is null");}
            }
        }, 0, 5000);
    }
```

Below is my log cat the place I am getting that null reference is right inside my startRandomButton() method:

```
                                                                       [ 10-22 14:34:13.423 15104:15141 D/         ]
                                                                       SurfaceInterface::setAsyncMode: set async mode 1
10-22 14:34:13.429 15104-15141/name.inserttitlenameD/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9bb040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9bb03290)
10-22 14:34:13.448 15104-15141/name.inserttitlename D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9bb040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9bb03290)
10-22 14:34:13.453 15104-15141/name.inserttitlename D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9bb040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9bb03290)
10-22 14:34:13.474 15104-15141/name.inserttitlename I/chatty: uid=10083(u0_a83) RenderThread identical 2 lines
10-22 14:34:15.124 15104-15141/name.inserttitlename D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9bb040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9bb03290)
10-22 14:34:17.606 15104-15141/name.inserttitlenameD/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9bb040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9bb03290)
10-22 14:34:17.628 15104-15141/name.inserttitlename I/chatty: uid=10083(u0_a83) RenderThread identical 1 line
10-22 14:34:17.638 15104-15141/name.inserttitlename D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9bb040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9bb03290)
10-22 14:34:18.272 15104-15141/name.inserttitlename D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9bb040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9bb03290)
10-22 14:34:18.467 15104-15141/name.inserttitlename D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9bb040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9bb03290)
10-22 14:34:18.480 15104-15141/name.inserttitlename D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9bb040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9bb03290)
10-22 14:34:18.487 15104-15141/name.inserttitlename D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9bb040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9bb03290)
10-22 14:34:20.156 15104-16453/com.example.name.inserttitlename D/Fragment one: Is null
10-22 14:34:25.157 15104-16453/com.example.name.inserttitlename D/Fragment one: Is null
10-22 14:34:50.161 15104-16453/com.example.name.inserttitlename I/chatty: uid=10083(u0_a83) Timer-1 identical 5 lines
```

complete fragment.java

```
package com.example.name.insertitlename;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.InflateException;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.logging.Level;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class LevelOneFragment extends Fragment {

    //creating variables
    private ImageView img;
    private ViewGroup viewer;
    TextView textCount;
    Button failButton;
    Button beginButton;
    TextView countDownBeginText;
    private TextView countDownMain;
    public int scoreCounter;

    public LevelOneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

 @Override
     public void onAttach(Context context){
       super.onAttach(context);
       Activity a;
      if(context instanceof Activity)
      {
          a=(Activity) context;
      }

     }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment



       // super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //setCont(R.layout.fragment_level_one);
       // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_one,container, false);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_one, container, false);

        //creating viewables and such
        viewer = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.view_level);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        failButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.failureButton);
        countDownMain = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countDownMain);
        countDownBeginText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countDownBeginText);
        beginButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.beginButton);

        /*if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeView(view);
            }
        }
        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_one, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {

        }*/

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
        img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        img.setOnTouchListener(new LevelOneFragment.ChoiceTouchListener());

        //begin random movement
        if(isAdded()) {
            startRandomButton(img);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("line 98 is", " is null");
        }

        //setting up button for failure CORRECT TO TAKE YOU TO THE MAIN MENU
        failButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainMenu.class));
            }
        });

        //setting countdown text to 3
        countDownBeginText.setText(":3");

        //begin countdown from three
        beginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View beginT) {
                CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(3*1000, 3) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        countDownBeginText.setText(":" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
                        //add possible sound here every tick
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        beginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        countDownBeginText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        //countdown from 60------- change parameters in count down timer to the time desired
                        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60*1000, 3) {
                            @Override
                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinishedMain) {

                                countDownMain.setText(":" + millisUntilFinishedMain/1000);
                                //add possible sound here every tick
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You lose", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                //rest of text in method is trial

                                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainMenu.class ));

                            }
                        }.start();

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
        return view; //inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_one,container, false);
    }
    //getting screen size
    public static Point getDisplaySize(@NonNull Context context){

        Point point = new Point();
        WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        manager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
        return point;
    }

    //randomly move
    public void randomMovement(ImageView img){
        //int   x = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(getActivity()).x);
        //int   y = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(getActivity()).y);

        if(isAdded()) {
            int   x = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(getActivity()).x);
            int   y = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(getActivity()).y);
            img.setY(y);
            img.setX(x);
        }
        else
            Log.d("Random mover is null", " is null");

    }

    final WeakReference<Activity> activityRef = getActivity();
    //creating timer
    public void startRandomButton(final ImageView img){
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(isAdded()){
         activityRef.get().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { //best method in the entire world-- use when trying to update ui in the background
                   @Override
                    public void run()
                   {
                       Activity activity = activityRef.get();
                        randomMovement(img);
                   }
                });}
                else
                {Log.d("Fragment one", "Is null");}
            }
        }, 0, 5000);
    }


    //listener for the moving ball
    private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){

            //Calling Counter
            textCount = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textViewCount);



            //switch statement for different events
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //this is where youre going to generate randmom location with id.setX(randomX) and id.setY(randomY)
                    randomMovement(img);

                    //Setting Counter to count when img is clicked
                    String countValue = textCount.getText().toString();
                    scoreCounter = Integer.parseInt(countValue);
                    scoreCounter++;
                    textCount.setText(String.valueOf(scoreCounter));
                    break;


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    break;


            }



            //checking score
            if(scoreCounter == 10 )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You win", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            viewer.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a specific fragment lifecycle method called "onActivityCreated" that assures that the activities "onCreate" method has been called. Don't assume it was properly created outside of this method.

Comment: can you please complete your code of your fragment, so that we can see where you initialized the `isAdded()`

Comment: yes I will make an edit for it right now.

Comment: Okay the edit has been made the entire fragment has been posted.

Comment: then how did you call this fragment?

Comment: @Cantum2 did you try to call the fragment in xml. like `<fragment
        android:name=".LevelOneFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />` coz I tried the code inside of your `startRandomButton()` and it is working fine. take a look it. [See the image](https://imgur.com/a/Rrayu)

Comment: I called it from one of my activites on a button press. The code runs but let me explain my problem some more. When I run my app i come up with the main menu when I click my levels button it takes me to my levelactivity I have it where when you press a level button it loads this fragment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see you invoke **super.onActivityCreated** from **onCreateView**.

Second, isAdded() is false doesn't mean getActivity() is null. There is also **mAdded** variable inside this method.

Third, if you have some timer, CountDownLatch - you should unsubscribe or stop it in either onStop or onDestroy callbacks to prevent memory leaks.

Forth, use [Handler#postDelayed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,long);) to post some action that should be done later on UI thread.

Comment: How do I make sure that it gets added. From my understanding I am getting this error because the activity is not added to the fragment correct? If that is correct, how do I add the activity to the fragment?

Comment: Use either onActivityCreated or onStart callback.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line: `super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);`. That line is not needed as you already defined the state of the fragment .hence the super class variant is not needed. Also do not get the context reference from onAttach, do it in onActivityCreated. Only that life cycle method garantees that the context is actually available.

Comment: So to do that do I just change my onAttatch to onActivityCreated and keep every thing else from the on attatch method the same? Where do I put that method? In side my onCreateView or what?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to multithreading. First you check that fragment is added and its activity reference is not null (as `getActivity().runOnUiThread` was not crashed), then you are trying to call `getActivity()` again hoping it is not null still. But it can be perfectly modified in between, before you call `getActivity()` second time.

Working solution here would be to store the activity reference in `WeakReference<Activity>` then call its `get()` method to work with Activity checking that it does not become null.

Another solution would be to store `getActivity()` result into some variable, but that could lead to leaks, when removing the Activity is impossible.

Comment: I like your Working solution. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Just `final WeakReference<Activity> activityRef = getActivity()` before `runOnUiThread` then add `Activity activity = activityRef.get();` inside `runOnUiThread`'s runnable, check it for null and if that's not null - pass to `randomMovement` as the second argument.

Comment: do i take `final WeakReference<Activity> activityRef = getActivity()` and put it directly before runOnUIThread like as follows... `final WeakReference<Activity> activityRef = getActivity().runonUiThread(new Runnable(){`

Comment: no, just `final WeakReference<Activity> activityRef = getActivity();` then you can use `activityRef` inside onRunUiThread what can be called as `activityRef.get().runOnUiThread(...`

Comment: Okay I did that now in my `final WeakReference<Activity> activityRef = getActivity()` I am a getting incompatible types error

Comment: If you would like to see the the entire fragment it has been added to the question. I have your recommendations added as well.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a mistake, use `WeakReference<Activity> activityRef = new WeakReference<>(getActivity())`

Comment: I did that and ran it. I am getting a null pointer exception on the line `activityRef.get().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {` any ideas?

Comment: Just don't call runOnUiThread when `activityRef.get()` returns null or catch NullPointerException as you wish

Comment: But I have to have randomMovement(img); be called every 5 seconds that is my entire goal for this fragment. Can you please help me some more. I have been stuck of so long and researched so much. This function right here is my entire application. Without it my app is nothing so I need `randomMovement(img)` to execute every 5 seconds in this fragment.